# AWS S3 Uploading File to Bucket using Postman not working

Tags: amazon-s3

I am using same credentials as for GET request , but the PUT request to upload any new file is failing with below error, I am updating below Authorization in Postman

```
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

AccessKey :-  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
SecretKey :-  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

AWS Region :- ap-south-1
Service Name :- S3

in the body I am choosing form-data and providing Key :- "text"  and value :- providing file path , but it errors out with the mentioned message.

Thanks
Santosh Varada

Answer (score 0):

Current AWS S3 API requests must be signed using AWS signature version 4. Your API call using version 2 which is not supported anymore.